# How to quit another application (not mine) from my app's service but not killing it

Tags: java, android

I am working on an app service that will display on top of another app that is currently on the foreground and if the user pressed on the back button it will destroy the service and exit the app too, but not killing it.

I had read many articles on stack overflow that tells me to use finish() or finishAffinity() but it only works if it is my own app activity.

Can I exit the app with its package name?

```
FrameLayout interceptorLayout = new FrameLayout(this) {

  @Override
  public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

    // Only fire on the ACTION_DOWN event, or you'll get two events (one for _DOWN, one for _UP)
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

      // Check if the HOME button is pressed
      if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

        Log.v(TAG, "BACK Button Pressed");
        onDestroy();
        // As we've taken action, we'll return true to prevent other apps from consuming the event as well
        return true;
      }
    } 

    // Otherwise don't intercept the event
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
  }
};
```

Comment: You cannot command other apps unless they explicitly expose API to do that (most do not).

Answer (score 0):

I am not recommending to close other app.
You can exit with other app's package name
Declare a permission for that in your AndroidManifest.xml file. here it is :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
```

and now use ActivityManager class to kill other apps and it will work.

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
am.killBackgroundProcesses(packageName);
```

Comment: but will it be able to exit foreground apps?

Comment: No, using this method, system immediately kill all background processes associated with the given package. This is the same as the kernel killing those processes to reclaim memory; the system will take care of restarting these processes in the future as needed.